# Windows Phone SDK - ListBox pressed effects

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone-7

I have a `ListBox` in my `Windows Phone` app, and I would like to have the downstate of a row have a '*pressed*' state much like that of the window phone OS applications menu. *I.e.*, when the user presses the left side of the `listbox` element, the left side of the element moves down, and when they press the right side of the element, then the right side goes down.

**Has anyone seen any way to replicate this?** I've googled a bunch, without much luck.

Cheers,
Brett

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's named [Tilt effect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff941094%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) and can be easily done eg. using Windows Phone Toolkit ([tutorial](http://windowsphonegeek.com/articles/Silverlight-for-WP7-Toolkit-TiltEffect-in-depth))

Comment: Exactly what I needed, thanks! I didn't know it was called a 'tilt'.